# How do I make a custom "Read More Blogs" button for my blog page

Tags: functions, css, pagination, html, buttons

I'm actually working on my custom wordpress theme. And, when I tried to develop a "Read More Blogs" button, I was unable. Because, all the examples I saw on internet was for pagination.

I need a single button that take me to blog page 2 from the blog homepage. Like, a single button used to be on Twitter(load more tweets). Please can you help????

I don't need pagination but a single load more blog posts button.

Answer (score 0):

This's the plugin you're looking for: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Load more posts, pages and comments using AJAX.